# AMQP broker written in python?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue, priority-queue, messagebroker

I'm looking for a `amqp broker` written in python. Right now I'm using [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) with pika bindings. RabbitMQ does the job, but it would be nice to find something simpler and more lightweight written in python.

The only one I have found so far is [SnakeMQ](http://www.snakemq.net/). But it does not(yet) support multiple queues, which is an requirement in my case.

Does anyone know if there are any alternatives written in python?

Answer (score -3):

[`Queue.Queue()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue) is batteries-included, couldn't be simpler.

Comment: Maybe I formulated the questing wrong. I'm looking for a message broker written in python, one that you can run as a "service".

Comment: I think the OP is looking for an inter-process message queue.  To my reading Queue.Queue() is useful only as in intra-process/inter-thread queue.